Intentando entender mis problemas de rendimiento en Jetpack Compose
He creado una clase con una función componible en Jetpack Compose para una aplicación que estoy creando. En la aplicación la idea es que varios usuarios puedan tocar un elemento componible y por cada dedo que lo toca se dibuja un circulo, a los 5 segundos se selecciona uno de ellos al azar, pero me pasan cosas raras que no consigo entender.
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun RandomScreen(
    viewModel: RandomViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    popUpToPreviousScreen: () -> Unit
) {

    val state = viewModel.state

    Scaffold(topBar = {

        TopAppBar(title = {

            Text(
                text = "Persona aleatoria",
                color = RangoonBlack,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontFamily = RobotoFamily,
            )
        }, navigationIcon = {

            IconButton(onClick = { popUpToPreviousScreen() }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }
        }, actions = {

            IconButton(onClick = { viewModel.setTimeRemaining(10) }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.MoreVert,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }
        })
    }) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(it)
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {

            val size by animateDpAsState(
                targetValue = if (state.isColorExpanded) 1000.dp else 0.dp,
                animationSpec = tween(2000),
                label = ""
            )

            LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.touchedPositions.size) {
                if (state.touchedPositions.size >= 2) {
                    val selectedUser = state.touchedPositions.entries
                        .random()
                        .key

                    val userSelected = state.touchedPositions.filter {
                        it.key == selectedUser
                    }

                    (0..5).reversed().forEach { countdown ->
                        delay(1000)
                        viewModel.setTimeRemaining(countdown)
                    }

                    viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(userSelected)
                    viewModel.isUserWinnerSelected(value = true)
                    viewModel.setIfIsColorExpanded(value = true)
                    viewModel.setTimeRemaining(value = 0)
                }
            }

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                text = "Cada jugador debe poner su dedo índice sobre el rectángulo de abajo, pasado dos segundos uno será elegido al azar.",
                color = GreyCloud,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                fontFamily = RobotoFamily,
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(1f)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                    .background(SoftPeach)
            ) {
                Canvas(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .pointerInput(state.isUserSelected) {
                            awaitEachGesture {

                                val down = awaitFirstDown()
                                down.consume()

                                while (state.isUserSelected.not()) {

                                    val touchedPositions = mutableMapOf<Long, Pair<Float, Float>>()
                                    val actualIds = mutableSetOf<Long>()

                                    val event = awaitPointerEvent()

                                    val anyPressed = event.changes.any { it.pressed }

                                    if (anyPressed) {

                                        Timber.i(
                                            "There are ${
                                                event.changes.size
                                            } fingers on screen"
                                        )

                                        if (event.type == PointerEventType.Press
                                            || event.type == PointerEventType.Move
                                        ) {
                                            event.changes.forEach { pointer ->
                                                val id = pointer.id.value - 1
                                                val x = pointer.position.x
                                                val y = pointer.position.y
                                                touchedPositions[id] = Pair(x, y)
                                                actualIds.add(id)
                                            }

                                            viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(touchedPositions)
                                        }

                                        if (event.type == PointerEventType.Release) {
                                            event.changes
                                                .filter { it.pressed }
                                                .forEach { pointer ->
                                                    actualIds.add(pointer.id.value - 1)
                                                }

                                            viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(touchedPositions)
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                        viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(touchedPositions)
                                        viewModel.setTimeRemaining(value = 0)

                                        Timber.i("All fingers have been raised")

                                        throw CancellationException()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    onDraw = {
                        if (state.isUserSelected.not() && state.touchedPositions.isNotEmpty()) {
                            state.touchedPositions.forEach { (id, position) ->
                                drawCircle(
                                    color = Color.Red,
                                    radius = 40.dp.toPx(),
                                    center = Offset(position.first, position.second)
                                )
                            }

                        } else {

                            state.touchedPositions.takeIf {
                                state.touchedPositions.isNotEmpty()
                            }?.forEach { (_, position) ->
                                drawCircle(
                                    color = DarkPink,
                                    radius = size.toPx(),
                                    center = Offset(position.first, position.second)
                                )
                                drawCircle(
                                    color = Color.White,
                                    radius = 40.dp.toPx(),
                                    center = Offset(position.first, position.second)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    })
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))

            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    if (state.isUserSelected) {
                        val updatedPositions = state.touchedPositions.toMutableMap()
                        updatedPositions.clear()
                        viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(updatedPositions)
                        viewModel.isUserWinnerSelected(false)
                        viewModel.setIfIsColorExpanded(false)
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(70.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    containerColor = if (state.isUserSelected) {
                        DarkPink
                    } else {
                        Color.Transparent
                    }
                ),
                border = BorderStroke(
                    width = 2.dp,
                    color = DarkPink
                )
            ) {

                Text(
                    text = if (state.timeRemaining > 0) {
                        state.timeRemaining.toString()

                    } else {
                        if (state.isUserSelected) {
                            "Volver a elegir"

                        } else {
                            "Coloca tu dedo arriba"
                        }
                    },
                    color = if (state.isUserSelected) {
                        Color.White
                    } else {
                        DarkPink
                    },
                    fontSize = if (state.timeRemaining > 0) {
                        20.sp

                    } else {
                        16.sp
                    },
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Mi ViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class RandomViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    var state by mutableStateOf(RandomState())
        private set

    fun isUserWinnerSelected(value: Boolean) {
        state = state.copy(
            isUserSelected = value
        )
    }

    fun setIfIsColorExpanded(value: Boolean) {
        state = state.copy(
            isColorExpanded = value
        )
    }

    fun setTimeRemaining(value: Int) {
        state = state.copy(
            timeRemaining = value
        )
    }

    fun updateTouchedPositions(
        touchedPositions: Map<Long, Pair<Float, Float>>
    ) {
        state = state.copy(
            touchedPositions = touchedPositions
        )
    }
}

Mi clase de estado
data class RandomState(
    val isUserSelected: Boolean = false,
    val touchedPositions: Map<Long, Pair<Float, Float>> = emptyMap(),
    val isColorExpanded: Boolean = false,
    val timeRemaining: Int = 0
)

En el Canvas que tengo dentro de mi Box, gestiono los eventos touch para que se pinten los círculos cada vez que un dedo toque el componente y en el LaunchedEffect gestiono la selección de un usuario aleatorio, que será el que actualice el mapa de punteros y pinte el círculo. Todo esto funciona bien, PERO.

Como puedes ver, el usuario puede mover su dedo en la pantalla y los
círculos se pintarán en esa posición, pero el rendimiento de esto es
lento, no se siente fluido, como si estuvieras jugando un juego a 15
FPS, es fluido pero no suave.

El siguiente problema que me estoy encontrando es la primera vez que
entro en pantalla, cuando tengo dos dedos y uno de ellos está
seleccionado, aunque en LaunchedEffect solo está seleccionado un
usuario, si colocamos un log dentro del else del método onDraw, nos
damos cuenta de que se pintan dos posiciones, aunque luego una tapa a
la otra y parece que lo hace bien.


Sospecho que es por la gestión de estados y recomposición, pero necesito una explicación de lo que ocurre.
